# Using django template variables in a external JavaScript file

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

I want to use the template variables in javascript file which is linked to the template.

For eg.

```
<!-- The template -->
<h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
<script src="{% static 'profile_page/js/index.js' %}"></script>
```

```
// The script file (a different file)
console.log('{{ user.username }}');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your `index.js` is also being generated by a Jinja template, then having `{{ user.username }}` inside `index.js` is going to be cumbersome to resolve.

The easier approach would be to generate a `<script>` tag, that contains the data your `index.js` would need. As `var username = ...;` would be accessible *within* the subsequent script.

```
<script>var username = {{ user.username|tojson }};</script>
<script src="{% static 'profile_page/js/index.js' %}"></script>
```

Now inside your `index.js` you can simply use the variable as your normally would, i.e.:

```js
console.log(username);
```